# Do native speakers use the following structure?

Tags: formality, syntactic-analysis

I have come across the structure below in an exercise book for non-native speakers of English.

"Let your teeth be brushed every day."

My question is: do native speakers use this structure? Actually, l feel that it is formal or old-fashioned, right?

Comment: Tangential to your question, but the word would be "construct" or "construction" rather than "structure". "structure" feels like a weird word to use in this context.

Comment: I think "structure" is more proper than " construction". Anyway, both are used. Thanks.

Comment: No, Parthian Shot is right. _Construction_ is the word you’re looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Let this be a good lesson in the difference between semantics and syntax:

One would *never* say such a thing about ones teeth. It is a very unnatural suggestion; if you are in a strange enough position for others to be brushing your teeth (you have an illness or have had an accident that prevents you from brushing your teeth yourself, allowing others to brush your teeth is probably not something you can choose to do (the actual 'letting') - presumably others will decide that you need to have your teeth brushed.

But...the general syntax is just fine. "Let (something) (present subjunctive)" is a very natural structure:

- Let the boy tie his own shoelaces (don't do it yourself)
- Let them eat cake (it's your birthday, or you are sarcastically insulting poor people)
- Let it be (zen-like advice to others while your rock band falls apart)

That's how you use the imperative 'Let'. It does not sound old-fashioned at all.

In the particular sentence you gave it sounds strange because the semantics is strange, not the syntax.

Comment: An excellent answer and worthy of an upvote. Please let me add a quibble or two. The *let* construction is how English presents the imperative mood in first and second persons. Your examples are all third person (The boy should tie his shoes, the poor should eat cake, and the universe should be left to itself.) The first person is also possible: *Let's get a drink." And this is the key to the unidiomatic brushing example. It can only be understood as an instruction to the 2nd-person owner of the teeth, but in the passive, it's directed to the 3rd-person teeth.

Comment: +1 There is at least one situation I can think of where the situation would make sense, but even then we wouldn't say it this way. The dentist would say: *Let **your parents/mom/dad/auntie/etc.** brush your teeth every day.** As @deadrat says, an imperative in the passive sounds weird, but put the brusher(s) back in there and it sounds fine. *Kids up to around age six don't have the dexterity to do a good job brushing their own teeth, but they certainly have enough strength and will to make it difficult for the adult(s) in their lives if they don't cooperate!

Comment: The construction is “Let [subject] [infinitive]”, not subjunctive, and I don’t think the example in the question necessarily implies that someone else does the brushing for you—in fact that’s the whole point of the passive: it removes the necessity of specifying the agent. This just isn’t a very natural way of phrasing it. @deadrat The _let_ construction is how English forms imperatives in the first and **third** persons, not the second.

Comment: @1006a Not all passive imperatives sound weird—there are cases where it sounds quite normal. The most common ones that spring to mind are introductions of the type “Let it be known that…”, etc., or mathematical statements à la “Let X be defined by YZπ”, etc.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet you're right, I should have said "**the** imperative" meaning *in this case*, or maybe "an **order** (to an individual)" meaning something less formally defined than the grammar term. Grammatically both of your examples are imperative, but I think they're—practically?  I'm sure you have a better way to define the difference for me!—a bit different from "let me do that" or "let it go". And of course even with direct commands we can use the passive specifically for the slightly archaic/formal feel, e.g "let it be so."

Comment: @1006a That’s active, not passive. But yes, going a bit archaic, passive imperatives become more common. “Let him be outlawed”, “let them never again be welcomed in any house”, “let the hordes of Sauron be defeated by the armies of the West”, etc. all sound perfectly fine in that style, but unlikely in regular conversation. (I think you meant ‘pragmatically’.)

Answer (score 2):

No. We would say "You should brush your teeth every day." The original sounds like a line in an old song.

Comment: You're right. The problem is that it's easy to get to the moon rather than convince those who insist on teaching students such old-fashioned structures.